# How to draw a system architecture with databases and shadows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, technical-drawing, tikz-matrix

My goal is to draw a complex system architecture.

Some approaches to do it are here [How to draw a layered architecture using Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102563/how-to-draw-a-layered-architecture-using-latex)

This approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102669/44348 seems to be very interesting, so one can make following modifications in that example:

1. Add shadow options `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}`
2. Add a way to cut shadows from a node, please, see here [remove drop shadow from one node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/remove-drop-shadow-from-one-node)
3. Make `nodes in empty cells=false`
4. Add `|[no shadows]|` to the cell that is going to be merged just to make a shape, anchor and name of this cell and prevent a mistake e.c.t.

I've some problems with:

1. Adding the pictures, like database [Display Database Instance Relationship with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123854/display-database-instance-relationship-with-tikz), for example

   in the cells `(stack-5-6) (stack-6-6)` with the name to make an arrow in future.
2. Creating an arbitrary block of nodes with the border and shadow, for example

   - we don't have a border and shadow near the cell `(stack-3-4)`,
   - we can't set a color of the matrix' body, because it'will be over the blocks with background.

   A way of adding pictures is described here [Nodes and matrix of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183896/nodes-and-matrix-of-nodes) but I can't adopt it well.

   A way of creating blocks as backround layers is described here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/kalman-filter/ but I can't have right borders and shadows. There is a problem to use `fit` option of `background` to get a good solution.

The MWE is

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadows,positioning,fit,matrix,shapes.geometric} % add shadows #1

    % a way to cut shadows in a cell #2
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/remove-drop-shadow-from-one-node
    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
    \makeatother


    \tikzstyle{background}=[rectangle, 
    fill=red!10,
    inner sep=0.2cm]
    %rounded corners=5mm] % it would be great to use rounded corners...

    \tikzstyle{backgroundN}=[rectangle, % to cut the background's node
    fill=white,
    inner sep=0.3cm]
    %rounded corners=5mm] % it would be great to use rounded corners...

    \tikzstyle{backgroundNN}=[rectangle, % to create the background's node
    fill=red!10,
    inner sep=0.2cm]
    %rounded corners=5mm] % it would be great to use rounded corners...


    \definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{124,156,205}
    \definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{73,121,193}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{202,217,126}
    \definecolor{mypink}{RGB}{233,198,235}

    \newcommand\widernode[5][widebox]{
    \node[
        #1,
        fit={(#2) (#3)},
        label=center:{\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#4}] (#5) {};
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt,outer sep=0pt, % just do nothing after modification
    boxstyle/.style={
    draw=white,
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners, drop shadow, %to get a shadow in below a node
    font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}},
    align=center,
    minimum height=30pt
    },
    box/.style={
    boxstyle=#1,
    text width=2.5cm},
    box/.default=mybluei,
    title/.style={font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}}},
    widebox/.style={draw=white,inner sep=0pt, rounded corners,fill=#1,drop shadow},
    widebox/.default=mybluei,
    mylabel/.style={font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}}},
    ]


    \matrix (stack) [draw=black,%  boxstyle=mybluei!40,%will overpaint blocks with background
    column sep=10pt, row sep=10pt, inner sep=4mm,%
        matrix of nodes,
            nodes={box, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center, inner sep=3pt},%  
            nodes in empty cells=false,% #3
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=none,draw=none,minimum height=3mm}},
    ]
    {
    |[no shadows]|&  & & &|[no shadows]|&|[no shadows]| \\ % #5
    RCP main & Authoring & Browsing & Publishing & Search&|[no shadows]|\\
    Rich Text &|[no shadows]| &|[no shadows]| &{XML\\ Export/Import} & MSP Export&|[no shadows]|\\
    Common & |[no shadows]|&|[no shadows]| & |[no shadows]|&|[no shadows]| &\node[rotate=10] {Hello};\\
    |[box=mypink]| Jtidy & |[no shadows]|&|[no shadows]| &|[box=mygreen]| GEF &|box=mygreen]| ICU4J & \\
    |[no shadows]|& && &|[no shadows]|&\\};


    \widernode[]{stack-1-1}{stack-1-5}{EPF Composer}{EPF} %#5



    \widernode{stack-3-2}{stack-3-3}{Library Management}{LMg}
    \widernode{stack-4-2}{stack-4-3}{UMA}{UMA}
    \widernode{stack-4-4}{stack-4-5}{Export/Import}{ExImp}
    \widernode[widebox=mygreen]{stack-5-2}{stack-5-3}{EMF}{EMF}
    \widernode[widebox=mygreen]{stack-6-1}{stack-6-5}{RCP Runtime}{RCPrun}



    \widernode{stack-2-6}{stack-3-6}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=center] (a) {Normal text\\works};
    \end{tikzpicture}}{NTWorks}



    \node [fit={(stack.south west)(stack.south east)},boxstyle=myblueii,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,below=3pt of stack.south,anchor=north,label={[mylabel]center:Java Runtime}] (JavaR) {};



    % smth to create an arbitrary block with a border and shadow
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node [background,
                fit=(stack-2-1) (stack-4-1)(stack-4-5),draw, drop shadow,
            ] {};
            \node [backgroundN,
                fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};
            \node [backgroundNN,draw, drop shadow,
                fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};                                       
        \end{pgfonlayer}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

The output AS-IS:
[image: AS_IS]

The output TO-BE:
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the MSP Export bit?

Comment: @cfr we don't have a border and shadow in background block near the MSP Export, i.e. (XML Export/Import.right), (Export/Import.above), (Search.below).

Comment: They look identical to me but since you got an answer it probably doesn't matter ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Problem 1: *Adding the pictures, like database [Display Database Instance Relationship with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123854/display-database-instance-relationship-with-tikz), for example in the cells `(stack-5-6) (stack-6-6)` with the name to make an arrow in future.*

Cells `(stack-5-6) (stack-6-6)` doesn't exist because you declared option `nodes in empty cells=false` and no nodes are created in empty cells. But you can use some other nodes as reference to place your database symbol. As an example I've used `(NTWorks|-RCPrun.south)`:

```
\node[database, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south] (DB3) at (NTWorks|-RCPrun.south) {DB3};
```

Problem 2: *Creating an arbitrary block of nodes with the border and shadow,*

You almost did it with:

```
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [background,
            fit=(stack-2-1) (stack-4-1)(stack-4-5),draw, drop shadow,
        ] {};
        \node [backgroundN,
            fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};
        \node [backgroundNN,draw, drop shadow,
            fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};                                       
    \end{pgfonlayer}
```

The problem was `\node [backgroundN, fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};`. This line introduced a wrong white border. Comment it out.

Some other points:

1. I've changed `tikzstyle` to `tikzset`. Please read [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
2. In node `NTWorks` you used a `tikzpicture` inside a `tikzpicture` which is not recommended. I've adopted syntax from `\widernode` to draw it.
3. Distance between columns 5 and 6 has been enlarged with `&[3mm]` in first row. This adds `3mm` to `column sep`. I've enlarged to better draw `fitting` nodes.
4. Right border of pink fitting box has been shifted to the right with `aux` coordinate. This way `MSP Export` border doesn't overwrite background border.
5. Data base symbol was taken from Thorsten Donig answer to [Display Database Instance Relationship with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123854/display-database-instance-relationship-with-tikz)

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadows,positioning,fit,matrix,shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows} % add shadows #1

    % a way to cut shadows in a cell #2
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/remove-drop-shadow-from-one-node
    \makeatletter
    \tikzset{no shadows/.code=\let\tikz@preactions\pgfutil@empty}
    \makeatother

    \tikzset{background/.style={rectangle, fill=red!10, inner sep=0.2cm},
              backgroundN/.style={rectangle, fill=white, inner sep=0.3cm},
              backgroundNN/.style={rectangle, fill=red!10, inner sep=0.2cm}}

    \definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{124,156,205}
    \definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{73,121,193}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{202,217,126}
    \definecolor{mypink}{RGB}{233,198,235}

    \newcommand\widernode[5][widebox]{
    \node[
        #1,
        fit={(#2) (#3)},
        label=center:{\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#4}] (#5) {};
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2pt,outer sep=0pt, % just do nothing after modification
    boxstyle/.style={
    draw=white,
    fill=#1,
    rounded corners, drop shadow, %to get a shadow in below a node
    font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}},
    align=center,
    minimum height=30pt
    },
    box/.style={
    boxstyle=#1,
    text width=2.5cm},
    box/.default=mybluei,
    title/.style={font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}}},
    widebox/.style={draw=white,inner sep=0pt, rounded corners,fill=#1,drop shadow},
    widebox/.default=mybluei,
    mylabel/.style={font={\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}}},
    database/.style={
      cylinder,
      cylinder uses custom fill,
      cylinder body fill=yellow!50,
      cylinder end fill=yellow!50,
      shape border rotate=90,
      aspect=0.25,
      draw
    }
    ]


    \matrix (stack) [draw=black,%  boxstyle=mybluei!40,%will overpaint blocks with background
    column sep=10pt, row sep=10pt, inner sep=4mm,%
        matrix of nodes,
            nodes={box, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center, inner sep=3pt},%  
            nodes in empty cells=false,% #3
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=none,draw=none,minimum height=3mm}},
    ]
    {
    |[no shadows]| & & & & |[no shadows]| &[3mm] |[no shadows]| \\ % #5
    RCP main & Authoring & Browsing & Publishing & Search&|[no shadows]| \\
    Rich Text &|[no shadows]| &|[no shadows]| &{XML\\ Export/Import} & MSP Export&|[no shadows]| \\
    Common & |[no shadows]| &|[no shadows]| & |[no shadows]| &|[no shadows]| &\node[rotate=10] {Hello};\\
    |[box=mypink]| Jtidy & |[no shadows]| & |[no shadows]| &|[box=mygreen]| GEF & |[box=mygreen]| ICU4J & \\
 |[no shadows]| & & & & |[no shadows]| &\\};


    \widernode[]{stack-1-1}{stack-1-5}{EPF Composer}{EPF} %#5

    \widernode{stack-3-2}{stack-3-3}{Library Management}{LMg}
    \widernode{stack-4-2}{stack-4-3}{UMA}{UMA}
    \widernode{stack-4-4}{stack-4-5}{Export/Import}{ExImp}
    \widernode[widebox=mygreen]{stack-5-2}{stack-5-3}{EMF}{EMF}
    \widernode[widebox=mygreen]{stack-6-1}{stack-6-5}{RCP Runtime}{RCPrun}

    \node[widebox,
        fit={(stack-2-6) (stack-3-6)},
        label={[text width=2.5cm, align=center]center:{\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}Normal text works}}] (NTWorks) {};

%    \widernode[widebox, text width=1.5cm, align=center]{stack-2-6}{stack-3-6}{Normal text works}{NTWorks}
%

    \node [fit={(stack.south west)(stack.south east)},boxstyle=myblueii,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,below=3pt of stack.south,anchor=north,label={[mylabel]center:Java Runtime}] (JavaR) {};

%
%
%    % smth to create an arbitrary block with a border and shadow
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \coordinate (aux) at ([xshift=2mm]stack-4-5.east);
            \node [background,
                fit=(stack-2-1) (stack-4-1) (aux), draw, drop shadow,
            ] {};
%            \node [backgroundN,
%                fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};
            \node [backgroundNN,draw, drop shadow,
                fit=(stack-3-5) ] {};                                       
        \end{pgfonlayer}

    \node[database, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=south] (DB3) at (NTWorks|-RCPrun.south) {DB3};

    \node[single arrow, draw, shape border rotate=90, anchor=south, fill=mybluei] at ([yshift=1mm]DB3.north) {\phantom{bpf}};

    \node[fit=(NTWorks) (DB3), draw, thick] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

**Update: Making holes**

I understand from your comment that your intention is to make `holes` in your scheme to represent that some blocks are not part from a set. From my point of view, it's difficult to draw arbitrary holes and respect shadowing. I could manage to draw an internal shadow for a rectangular hole and I hope something similar could be applied to arbitrary holes but I think this should be another question.

What I've done has been to apply [Paul Gaborit's `shadowed` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185853/1952) adapted to default shadow style (first lines from section 66.3.1 Drop Shadows in pgfmanual.pdf).

```
shadowed/.style={postaction={draw=black!50, opacity=.5, line width=.5ex}}
```

and use this style to draw an internal shadow to certain rectangular node:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\coordinate (aux) at ([xshift=2mm]stack-4-5.east);
\node [background, fit=(stack-2-1) (stack-4-1) (aux), 
       draw, drop shadow] {};
%draw a white `background` around node
\node [fill=white, fit=(stack-3-5)] (hole) {};     
%draw an internal shadow 
\begin{scope}
    \clip (hole.south west) rectangle (hole.north east);                                  
    \path[shadowed] (hole.south west) |- (hole.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

** 2nd Update: Non rectangular background

You don't need to use rectangular backgrounds because a `drop shadow` can be also applied to any closed path. The difficult part is how to define the complex background. Next code show an example. I've still used the rectangular (although not drawn neither filled) background as reference to compoun a complex closed shape. Just changed code is provided:

```
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [
            fit=(stack-2-1) (stack-4-5), 
        ] (BigGroup) {};

        \draw[green, fill=green!30, very thick, drop shadow] (BigGroup.north west) -| ([shift={(-2mm,-3mm)}]stack-3-5.south west) -| (BigGroup.south east) -| ([shift={(-2mm,3mm)}]ExImp.north west)-|([xshift=-2mm]UMA.west|-BigGroup.south)-|cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Perhaps, I didn't explain clear an idea about MSF-Export. It'll be very useful to have a tool to exclude some nodes (cells) from the block made with background, for example, please see [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~galicia/design.html). "Kernel" block is excluded from "Services", which has not-rectangle-like shape, surrounded with border and shadow. My code with "wrong white clolor" was an attempt to exclude MSF-Export from the background block. The next step might be drawing missing lines and shadows in the backgound block or to try another designing way...

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: I've updated the answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes that is what I mean. Do you have an idea how to control the shifting of the hole in each particular direction (east, west, north, south)? For example it would be great to cut the part of the backround block, which is close to `(MSP Export.east)`.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko: `\path[shadowed] (hole.north west) -- (hole.north east);`? I'm not sure to understand you.

Comment: One possible way is to create two new points `\coordinate (myAux) at ([xshift=2mm]stack-3-5.east);`and `\coordinate (myAuxX) at ([yshift=4mm]stack-2-5.north);` and modify `hole`: `\node [fill=white, fit=(stack-2-5)(stack-3-5)(myAux)(myAuxX)] (hole) {};`. However in this case we have to guess what `yshift, xshift`to choose.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko I've made a second update.

Comment: The perfect answer!

Comment: Dear Ignasi, do you know the way to scale our diagramm? I've tried many ways, but they don't work correctly. For example, this one [for matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144542/44348) paints a picture over some text of the paper and doesn't scale `pgfonlayer` (Non rectangular background).

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko Instead of making new questions through comments, it's better to write new questions linking them to this one. This way your audience will be wider and don't have to trust in my limited knowledge.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4340/44348). Just add `\resizebox{0.2\textwidth}{!}{%\my_tikzpicture_begin_end }`.