# TikZ tree with a line crossing the edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Does somebody help me to draw the following tree in TikZ (with different colors at leaves)?
I have no idea how to draw particularly the horizontal line crossing the edges.

Thank you.
Best[image]

My code is here:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodes={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=.8ex}, ->, 
    level distance=2cm, growth parent anchor=south
]

\Tree 
[.\node(p0){move-stack(p1a,q)}; 
    \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c11,c12)}; 
    [.\node(p1){move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}; 
        \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{take-and-put(...)}; 
        \node(p3){take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)};
        \node(p4){put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)};
    ]
    [.\node(p2){move-stack(p1a,p1b)}; 
        \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c12,pallet)}; 
        [.\node(p5){move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)};
            \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{take-and-put(...)}; 
            \node(p7){take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)};
            \node(p8){put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)};
        ]
        [.\node(p6){move-stack(p1a,p1b)}; ] 
    ] 
]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.ae! what you try so far? horizontal line is relative simple to add (just name nodes and draw them as `\draw[->] ([yshift=...] <node name>) -- ...`, but wrote your tree from scratch is not fun ..:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution with `forest`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={draw, rounded corners,
             fill = white,
       inner xsep = 1mm,
       inner ysep = 2mm,
                    drop shadow,
    % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             grow = south,
    parent anchor = south,
     child anchor = north,
             edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
        EL/.style = {edge label={node[midway, font=\small, inner sep=1pt, anchor=south east]{#1}},},
        FB/.style = {fill=blue!30},
            s sep = 3mm,        % sibling distance
            l sep = 12mm,       % level distance
              }
[{move-stack(p1a,q)}
    [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)},             name=p1,
     EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c11,c12)}
        [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)},        FB, name=p3,
         EL={take-and-put(...)}
         ]
        [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},      FB, name=p4
        ]
     ]
    [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)},                         name=p2,
        [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)},         name=p5,
         EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c12,pallet)}
            [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)},    FB, name=p7,
             EL={take-and-put(...)}
             ]
            [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},  FB, name=p8,
             ]
         ]
        [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)},                     name=p6,
         label=below:{do-nothing(p1a,p1b)}
        ]
    ]
]
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using int(\x-1)] in {2,4,6,8}
{
    \draw[gray, very thick, -stealth]
        ([shift={(-3mm,3mm)}] p\y.north) -- ([shift={(3mm,3mm)}] p\x.north);
}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) But it is very misleading to describe `l sep` and `s sep` as sibling and level distances. They are not. They are *minimum* distances, just as `minimum width` is a minimum size when talking about nodes.

Comment: @cfrm, you have right.  comments deleted.

Comment: Thank you all. I liked the approach to remove the space between the siblings :)

Comment: @VahidMokhtari, instead saying "thank you" here is more preferred to vote good answer (by clicking on up-pen at top left side of answer) and accept ones, which solve your problem on the best way (by clicking on check mark, also at top left side of answer)

Answer (score 6):

To fill the background of a leaf, use `\node [fill=<colour>] ..`.  I made a style with that, so if you want to change the colour, just modify the style.

Zarko's suggestion for the arrows work fine, but you need to specify the anchor as well, so use e.g. `\draw [->] ([yshift=3mm]p1.north) -- ([yshift=3mm]p2.north);`. I used a `\foreach` loop to draw the arrows, which makes the code a bit shorter.

For the do-nothing, you can add a `label` to the node, i.e. `\node [label={below:do-nothing(p1a,p1b)}] (p6){move-stack(p1a,p1b)};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodes={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=.8ex}, ->, 
    level distance=2cm, growth parent anchor=south,
    endleaf/.style={fill=blue!30}
]

\Tree 
[.\node(p0){move-stack(p1a,q)}; 
    \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c11,c12)}; 
    [.\node(p1){move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}; 
        \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{take-and-put(...)}; 
        \node [endleaf] (p3){take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)};
        \node [endleaf] (p4){put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)};
    ]
    [.\node(p2){move-stack(p1a,p1b)}; 
        \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c12,pallet)}; 
        [.\node(p5){move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)};
            \edge node[draw=none,auto=right]{take-and-put(...)}; 
            \node [endleaf] (p7){take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)};
            \node [endleaf] (p8){put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)}; 
        ]
        [.\node [label={below:do-nothing(p1a,p1b)}] (p6){move-stack(p1a,p1b)}; ] 
    ] 
]

\foreach [evaluate={\y=int(\x-1)}] \x in {2,4,6,8}
    \draw [-latex] ([yshift=3mm]p\y.north) -- ([yshift=3mm]p\x.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Have you also an idea to add "do-nothing(p1a,p1b)" below the most right-bottom node (as in my sample figure)?
I don't know how to add that text!

Comment: @VahidMokhtari Hadn't noticed that one, see updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is shamelessly based on [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443859/) and is, basically, a more automated form of that solution, with slightly more flexible and streamlined code.

```
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
```

Where possible, my code uses anchors which are sensitive to the direction of the tree's growth. This is especially useful when specifying the code for the horizontal arrows, but good practice generally as it makes for greater flexibility.

```
  where n children=0{fill=blue!50!gray!25}{fill=white},
```

This saves having to apply the colour manually to each node which needs it. Since all those nodes are leaves and no leaves aren't coloured, it makes sense to use this feature to have Forest determine which ones to fill with blue and which with white.

```
  where={>O_={n}{1}}{tikz+={\draw [thick, shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt, -{Triangle[width=6pt,length=6pt]}] ([yshift=10pt].-children) -- ([yshift=10pt]!s.-children); }}{}
```

This code draws the horizontal arrows, without relying on the manual addition of `name` to each node. Every first child has a sibling and every such pair has an arrow above, but no other cases need arrows, so we use a node's being the first to decide whether or not to draw the arrow.

```
([yshift=10pt].-children) -- ([yshift=10pt]!s.-children)
```

This specifies the path from 10pt above the anchor `.-children` of the current node to 10pt above the anchor `.-children` of its sibling (`!s`). Again, `.-children` depends on the direction of growth of three tree.

I've also used arrows from `arrows.meta` as arrows such as `-stealth` are considered deprecated and do not support the new, more flexible and consistent syntax.

[image: output]

Complete code;

```
% addaswyd o ateb Zarko: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443859/
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,
    rounded corners=.8ex,
    drop shadow,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge+={draw, semithick, -{Triangle[width=4pt,length=4pt]}},
    EL/.style={edge label={node[midway, font=\small\sffamily, anchor=south east, inner sep=1pt]{#1}},},
    FB/.style={fill=blue!30},
    l sep*=3,   
  },
  where n children=0{fill=blue!50!gray!25}{fill=white},
  where={>O_={n}{1}}{tikz+={\draw [thick, shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt, -{Triangle[width=6pt,length=6pt]}] ([yshift=10pt].-children) -- ([yshift=10pt]!s.-children); }}{}
  [{move-stack(p1a,q)}
    [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}, EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c11,c12)}
      [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)}, EL={take-and-put(...)}
      ]
      [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},       
      ]
    ]
    [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)},                         
      [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}, EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c12,pallet)}
        [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)}, EL={take-and-put(...)}
        ]
        [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},   
        ]
      ]
      [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)}, label={[font=\small\sffamily]below:{do-nothing(p1a,p1b)}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

---

@cfr: Please feel free to remove the following. I just verified that your code works fine and could not resist to cast some shadows (as the groundhog day was too long ago ;-). -marmot

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
 shadowed/.style={%
 preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0,-2pt)}},draw=gray,very thick,draw opacity=.2},
 preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0,-3pt)}},draw=gray,very thick,draw opacity=.1},
 preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0,-4pt)}},draw=gray,very thick,draw opacity=.05},
 },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,
    rounded corners=.8ex,
    blur shadow,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={shadowed, semithick, -{Triangle[width=4pt,length=4pt]}},
    EL/.style={edge label={node[midway, font=\small\sffamily, anchor=south east, inner sep=1pt]{#1}},},
    FB/.style={fill=blue!30},
    l sep*=3,   
  },
  where n children=0{fill=blue!50!gray!25}{fill=white},
  where={>O_={n}{1}}{tikz+={\draw [shadowed,thick, shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt, -{Triangle[width=6pt,length=6pt]}] ([yshift=10pt].-children) -- ([yshift=10pt]!s.-children); }}{}
  [{move-stack(p1a,q)}
    [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}, EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c11,c12)}
      [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)}, EL={take-and-put(...)}
      ]
      [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},       
      ]
    ]
    [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)},                         
      [{move-topmost-container(p1a,p1b)}, EL={recursive-move(p1a,p1b,c12,pallet)}
        [{take(crane1,l1a,c11,c12,p1a)}, EL={take-and-put(...)}
        ]
        [{put(crane1,l1b,c11,pallet,p1b)},   
        ]
      ]
      [{move-stack(p1a,p1b)},fill=white,label={[font=\small\sffamily]below:{do-nothing(p1a,p1b)}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 as usual. Maybe with `shadows.blur` and `shadowed` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218929/121799) it might come even closer to the OP's screen shot.

Comment: Note in the OPs image the move-stack node on the right is not coloured.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your help and your approach, however the code doesn't compile completely.

Comment: @VahidMokhtari This is not my code but nevertheless (or because of that;-) it compiles fine.

Comment: @VahidMokhtari What happens? Do you get an error? Which? Is your TeX distribution up to date? It compiles fine for me, so unless you provide some information, it's impossible to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @cfr I am getting this error for your code:

`! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `O' or `O_' (in '>O_={n}{1}').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.44 \end{forest}
                 
?`

Comment: @VahidMokhtari You need to update your installation of TeX. You have rather an old version of Forest.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, good spot. If anybody actually wants to use this, leave a comment and I'll fix the colouring pattern.

Comment: The error mentioned by @VahidMokhtari is just due to outdated software and not a result of the code here. (Well, it is a result in the sense that the code here uses current Forest, but there's no error in the code, as it were.)